# Creating custom funcitonin wordpress to return data from database

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom image uploader for my wordpress admin panel and need to retrieve the data from the wp_options table. I have wrritne the below function:

```
//function to get all slider images
function getSliderImages(){
    global $wpdb, $theme_shortname;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options AS o1 
    WHERE o1.option_name LIKE '%".$theme_shortname."_header_image%'";
    $imgs = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $images = array();
    //loop through images and remove unusable results
    foreach($imgs as $i){
        $id = substr($i['option_name'],0,-1);
        if(is_numeric($id)){
            $images[] = $i['option_value'];
        }
    }

    return($images);
}
```

How do I access the returned array in header.php on the front end? this function is currently in themes/themename/functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a global function that is available within all of your template files. You can simply use `<?php $images = getSliderImages(); ?>` in any of your templates.

Comment: This was the way i tried it first but I get this error from the function. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/wadem/Sites/gpsite/wp-content/themes/PracticeInABox/functions.php on line 747 The line it refers to is $id = substr($i['option_name'],0,-1);

Comment: try `$i->option_name` and `$i->option_value`